# SQL Where statement for strings

Tags: sql

I have a column that's string and I would like to use a `WHERE` statement for all strings that begin with the "sea_"

Any ideas on how to achieve that will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: WHERE your_string LIKE 'sea%'

Comment: Are you looking for `LIKE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly your where clause should do. If necessary, you should please add more information. Anyway, in general, you can do such a select:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'sea_%'
```

The % means that zero, one or more characters can follow.
If you need further conditions like an exact number of trailing characters etc., you please must specify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to ignore Upper/Lower case , it can help you

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(column) LIKE 'sea_%'
```

Comment: In usual DB's, LIKE operator performs case-insensitive pattern match, so it's not required to add an upper or lower. But of course, it can help for beginners to make it clear ;)

Comment: thanks for mentioning :)))but I checked on oracle and it didn't perform case-senseitive

Comment: Yes, that's just what I wrote: Usually, DB colums and like operators are not case sensitive. Therefore, it is not necessary to add lower. It is only case sensitive when you define it as such.

Comment: @xynb Thanks so much for your proposed solution too

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that underscore `_` is itself a placeholder for any single character which must be escaped in order to use it literally.

The criteria you should use to ensure an underscore is also present is

```
where column like 'sea[_]%';
```

You can also define your own explicit escape character, such as

```
where column like 'sea@_%' escape '@';
```